# Java boolean null cast

Tags: java

I have the following code snippet:

```java
Boolean var = false;
boolean var1 = (var = null);
    
if (var1) {
    // It compiles
}
if (var = null) {
    // It compiles
}
```

Why does it compile?

In the `Boolean` class I found the following:

```java
public static boolean parseBoolean(String s) {
    return ((s != null) && s.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

Does it mean that is `null` considered as `false`? Why the result of `=` operation on `boolean` is `false`? What the practical reason of this behavior?

Comment: Why don't you start your program and see what happens? Btw: `if(null=var)` won't compile...

Comment: `if(null=var)` never compile.

Comment: P.S: Var1 might be true. = will asign a value == will compare. In "boolean var1=(var=null);" the parentesis is just a statement. And in "if(null=var){" it should not compile. You can't assing a value to null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding the first question *Why does it compile?*

#### Unedited version: It does not compile

It will give a compile error since `if (null = var)` is not valid java code. You cannot assign something to `null`, you can only ever assign `null` to something.

You might want to use the `==` instead comparing `var` and `null` for equality.

Beyond that, at runtime you will get an `NPE` as @Ctx already correctly mentioned. The line `boolean var1 = (var = null);` will firstly assign `null` to `var`, then the assignment operator `=` will return what it has just assigned (`null`) and try to assign that to the `boolean var1`, which throws a NullPointerException.

> *Does it mean that is `null` considered as `false`?*

Not really. Only when parsing a `String` which is `null` this is treated as `false`. That is basically the only place / situation.

#### After the edit changing `null = var` to `var = null`:

Now your code will actually compile and crash with a NullPointerException. Let's go through what happens here step by step:

- `Boolean var = false;` — A `Boolean` object is created by autoboxing the `boolean` value `false`.
- `boolean var1 = (var = null);` — The first operation is `(var = null)` which assigns `null` to `var`. `=` therefore returns `null`. The statement then is "equivalent" to `boolean var1 = null` which the compiler *would* reject.

  Unfortunately, the compiler is not capable of deducing that the statement `boolean var1 = (var = null);` would always lead to the invalid assignment `boolean var1 = null`. The code therefore compiles fine, but crashes at runtime.

Comment: Mind that OP silenty invalidated your answer by manipulating the question. But since the edit history still exists, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: *"Only when parsing a `String` which is `null` this is treated as `false`"* — Do you mean when using `Boolean.valueOf(null)`?

Comment: @MCEmperor OP was talking about code from `Boolean.parseBoolean`, not sure what `valueOf` does exactly.

Answer (score 8):

Assigning `null` to a native type (like `boolean`, `int`, etc.) will result in a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all your code will not compile. It will give you a compilation error on the `if (null = var) {` line.
2. Second thing is that while initializing a primitive data type, you can't assign a `null` value. If you assigning it on compile time, it will give you a compilation error. But if you doing it on run time, it gives a NullPointerException. Just like that **boolean b = null;** is not valid in Java. But **Boolean bObj = null;** is valid. While in your code when your are doing **(var = null)** it actually returns `null`. Hence, `boolean var1 = (var = null)` becomes `boolean var1 = null`. Here, the variable `var1` is assigned with `null` value with a run time basis. So, it will give a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

At first, do you know the difference between `Boolean` and `boolean`? Because assign `null` to `boolean` will cause `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

Code would be written like this:

```java
Boolean var = false;
boolean var1 = (var == null);
if (var1) {
    // It compiles
}
if (var == null) {
    // It compiles
}
```

The reason of `var != null` is that `null` and `Boolean.FALSE` do not share the same memory.

Comment: `boolean var1=(var=null);` compiles fine, but will cause an exception during runtime.

Comment: You're right, can you explain why it can complile, for there is no return value of `=`

Comment: There is a return value: the value of the variable. That is why you can also write `int a, b, c; a = b = c = 1;`

Comment: Yes, now I see why `var1 = (var = null)` have an exception during runtime. The complier don't know the return value of `(var = null)`, so it can compile, but when running, for `var = null` will return `null`, and an error will happen when executing expression `boolean var1 = null`

Comment: Correct. The JVM tries to unbox the value of `var`, but fails, because it can't unbox `null` into a meaningful value for a primitive type.